# Optimality criterion for mean estimators

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, estimators

Assume a sample size of $n>5$, a given variance $\sigma^2 > 0$ and a $\delta \in (2e^{-n/4}, 1/2)$.

Proof that there exists a distribution with variance $\sigma^2$ such that for any mean estimator:

$P (\{ | \widehat{\mu_n} - \mu | > \sigma \sqrt{\frac{log(1/\delta)}{n}} \}) \geq \delta$

This is Theorem 3.1 in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282072546_Sub-Gaussian_mean_estimators). And a proof is provided but I do not understand two steps. First of all why is the distribution of the independent pair not $P(X_i=Y_i=0)=(1-p)^2$?

And why is the part on the start of p.16 correct? I am having troubles understanding the step from equation 1 to 2 and 2 to 3.